# Проблема с ссылками

Tags: css

Всем добрый день столкнулся с проблемой задаю для ссылок следующие CSS

```
.blocsSushMenu a {
position: relative;
outline: rgb(255, 0, 0) solid 0px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
font-size: 17px;
padding: 0px 10px 10px;
width: 202px;
z-index: 5;
height: 212px;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Во всех браузерах все нормально клик по всей площади происходит но не в IE подскажите как решить проблему с IE

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/YzfVG/

Comment: Вижу что работает у меня другие ссылки на сайте с подобными стилями тоже работают а некоторые не работают и понять не могу почему. Наследственно на ссылки ничего не влияет.